# JavaScript: How to pass and reset an incremental value to IndexedDB store get method?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

The following code passes an argument variable `nextId` to the `IndexedDB` Store get method and the corresponding records are returned if the argument passed matches the key of the record.

Initially I created another method which gets all records into an array, then I returned the array length. However my loop simply gets the last value as it should.

The code looks like this: Note: This method `getEmployeeCount()` holds the array length and used like below:

```
    var something;
    for ( var i = 1; i <= getEmployeeCount(); i ++ )  {
        something = i;
    }
```

*Experimental Working Code*:

```
function displaySingleRecord() {

    var output = document.getElementById( 'display' );
    output.textContent = "";

    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');

    var  nextId = incre ++;
    var request = store.get(nextId.toString());

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        dbStatusMessage('Cannot Retrieve data.', 1);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {

        output.innerHTML = '<b>Employee ID:</b> '  + request.result.employeeId  + ' <br> ' +
                           '<b>First Name:</b>  '  + request.result.firstName   + ' <br> ' +
                           '<b>Last Name:</b>   '  + request.result.lastName    + ' <br> ' +
                           '<b>Email:</b>       '  + request.result.email       + ' <br> ' +
                           '<b>Department:</b>  '  + request.result.department;
    };
}
```

How do I reset the increment to 1 when the records reaches the end or last record. I tried using the output which is a p tag but did not work.

```
if ( output.textContent === '')
     doReset;
```

**UPDATE:** *Working solution:*

One of the primary issues I faced is getting the total records from the cursor and than using this number as a threshold to reset the increment process. The steps below illustrate what I did to a get working solution:

**Step one:**
I used a `hidden field` to persist the incremental value and return it back to the method performing the increment: I also added two buttons: `next` and `prev`.

*HTML:*

```
<!--Hidden Field-->
<input id="currentValue" value="0" type="hidden" />

<a id="next" href="/">Next</a>
<a id="prev" href="/">Previous</a>

<!--Output value here-->
<p id="output"></p>
```

Next, I need to get the total records from a data store: I do this by getting the length of the array in the `getTotalRecordCount` method.
Remember, when we increment, we need to know if the end has reached, this way we are not clicking next and seeing empty results, we simply reset to one. Note: We are passing the record array to the callback to avoid issues with `IndexedDB` async architectural:

*Method to get total record from store:*

```
function getTotalRecordCount(callback) {

    var IDBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open(Database.Name, Database.Version);

    IDBOpenRequest.onerror = function () {
        dbStatusMessage('Database failed to open.', 1000);
    };

    IDBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {

        var objectStore = getObjectStore(Database.Store.USGeological, 
            Database.ReadWrite, e.target.result);

        var record = [];
        var cursorRequest = objectStore.openCursor();

        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
            var cursor = e.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                record.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            } else {

                callback(record);
            }
        };

        e.target.result.close();
    };
}
```

Next: we access the record array from the callback in the `getNextId` method.

*Code:*

```
function getNextId(val) {

    getTotalRecordCount(function (record){

    // Get initial or current value from hidden field.    
    var currentValue = document.getElementById('currentValue');

    var newValue = parseInt(currentValue.value,10) + val;

    // Use the record array from the callbck, pass it's length.
    // IMPORTANT: If our current position or count is greater 
    // than array length we go back to 1.   

    if (newValue > parseInt(record.length) || newValue <= 0) {
        newValue = 1;
    }

        currentValue.value = newValue;
        getRecordByRotatingId(newValue);

    });
}
```

Finally: we display our result to screen: This code simply passes the incremental value to the `get method` and displays the data in reference to the current id:

Note: This is developmental code, I am not using all of the call back events, for example: In the try catch I am purposely not using the e.message in the catch block.

```
   function getRecordByRotatingId(value) {

        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.textContent = "";

        var IDBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open(Database.Name, Database.Version);

        IDBOpenRequest.onerror = function () {
            dbStatusMessage('Database failed to open.', 1000);
        };

        IDBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {

            var objectStore = getObjectStore(Database.Store.USGeological,
                Database.ReadOnly, e.target.result);

            var request = objectStore.get(value);

            request.onsuccess = function () {

                try {

                    output.innerHTML = '<b>State ID:</b> ' + 
                        request.result.StateId +  ' <br> ' +
                        '<b>State:</b>  ' + request.result.StateName + 
                        ' <br> ' + '<b>Abbreviation:</b>   ' + 
                        request.result.StateAbbreviation;

                } catch (e) {

                    dbStatusMessage('Data does not exist.', 1000);
                }
            };

            request.onerror = function () {
                dbStatusMessage('Data does not exist.', 1000);
            };

            e.target.result.close();
        };
}
```

This code will have a performance hit in production with large data result set, that's because it calls the cursor each time when next or previous is clicked. We could place the total record count into memory (local storage) and update each time pages is loaded.

**UPDATE:** 
After my initial update above, I discovered you can also get the total record in an object store by using the index count method:
With that, I have consolidated the method to just a single method:

[IDBIndex.count()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/count)

```
function getRecordByNextId(val) {

    var IDBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open(Database.Name, Database.Version);

    IDBOpenRequest.onerror = function () {
        dbStatusMessage('Database failed to open.', 1000);
    };

    IDBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {

        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.textContent = "";

        var objectStore = getObjectStore(Database.Store.USGeological,
            Database.ReadOnly, e.target.result);

        var myIndex = objectStore.index('StateName');
        var request = myIndex.count();

        request.onsuccess = function () {

            var currentValue = document.getElementById('currentValue');
            var newValue = parseInt(currentValue.value, 10) + val;

           if (newValue > parseInt(request.result) || newValue <= 0) {
                newValue = 1;
            }

            currentValue.value = newValue;

            var dataRequest = objectStore.get(parseInt(currentValue.value));

            dataRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {

                output.innerHTML = '<b>State ID:</b> ' + dataRequest.result.StateId
                    + ' <br> ' + '<b>State:</b>  ' + dataRequest.result.StateName +
                    ' <br> ' + '<b>Abbreviation:</b>   ' +
                    dataRequest.result.StateAbbreviation;
            };
        };


        e.target.result.close();
    };
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear as you're mixing the database operations with the output logic. Are you trying to detect when you've reached the last record?

If so: request.result will be the undefined value when you access a record that doesn't exist, i.e. when you've iterated through all of your records.

This assumes that your records have contiguous IDs (there are no gaps) and that you don't have records where the value is actually undefined (unusual but allowed). In those cases you probably want to use a cursor, even if you don't call continue().

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't find your question to be very clear but maybe that is just me. If I understand you at all, maybe I can make the suggestion that you do something like the following:

```
function iterateEmployees(db) {
  var tx = db.transaction(DB_STORE_NAME);
  var store = tx.objectStore(DB_STORE_NAME);
  var request = store.openCursor();
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var employee = cursor.value;
      printEmployeeDetails(employee);
      cursor.continue(); // advance the cursor by 1
    } else {
      // no more employees, or no employees found at all
      doSomethingAfterListingEmployees();
    }
  };
}

function printEmployeeDetails(employee) {
  output.innerHTML += '<p>Id: ' + employee.employeeId + '</p>' +
    'etc ...';
}
```

Edit, after reading your comment, what you probably want to do is learn about cursor.advance. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/advance. What you could do is open a cursor each time the user clicks the button, and then advance by a counter that is incremented each time the user clicks the button.

Comment: In a nutshell, I am simply attempting to display the data individually as I clicked a button. The next record is displayed based on an incremental argument, this is why I used the `get` method, then passing a value.

When I use your code, the cursor moves directly to the end of the data. It does not step through incrementally as needed unless with an alert method.

Again, I am simply attempting to display each record as the user clicks. Preferably, I would like to go forward and backwards.

Thank you so much.